# Unable to access state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to access state inside of my methods but this is always null. Can anyone explain to me what I need to do to give my methods reference to state and why it needs to be done?

```
import * as React from 'react';


interface IProps {
  enabled?:boolean;
}
interface IState {
  itemCount?: number;
}

class ItemCounter extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  public state : IState
  constructor(props: IProps) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         itemCount: 0
      };

  }
public handleIncrement = () => {
  if(this.state.itemCount != null){
    this.setState({itemCount: this.state.itemCount++});
  }
};
public handleDecrement = () => {
  if(this.state.itemCount != null){
    this.setState({itemCount: this.state.itemCount--});
  }
};
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.itemCount}
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrement}>Add Item</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleDecrement}>Remove Item</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ItemCounter;
```

Comment: What's this `public` for? are you using some package? https://codesandbox.io/s/6j42kr2j4w

Comment: That works nicely. I made it public because the linter for create-react-app wont compile the code unless the methods are decorated with prviate, public or protected.

Comment: If that's what you're interested I would disable it because it's terrible advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed defining a number of handleIncrement and handleDecrement

```
public handleIncrement = () => {
  if(this.state.itemCount != null){
    this.setState({itemCount: this.state.itemCount+1});
  }
};
public handleDecrement = () => {
  if(this.state.itemCount != null){
    this.setState({itemCount: this.state.itemCount-1});
  }
};
```

[image: Edit 6j42kr2j4w]

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. Thank you for taking the time to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

using `++` or `--` on a React `state` property is a no-no.  both of those operators will mutate the data they are used on, which is something you never want to so on a React `state`

Comment: on a side note... `this.state.itemCount++` would first return the value of `this.state.itemCount` and then would increase the value by one. `++this.state.itemCount` would increase the value by one, then return the new increased value.  But again, not something that can be done on a React `state`